# Change Size product RMA

Tags: magento2, magento-1.9, rma

Hi I would like to know how to change the size of a product in an RMA request please?
Thank you

Comment: RMA request form?

Comment: a customer made a return request that was approved, but the product size needs to be changed

Comment: you need to add more details to your question to help you